# FormatterGenerator threw an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

There is a thread on the DotNetNuke page [here](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Forums/forumid/107/postid/458730/scope/posts.aspx) that describes the error being handled, although none of those solutions have helped and the thread seems to be dead.

I've found the error occurs most frequently when trying to get to Site Settings or when clicking on your login name to go to a profile.

The error is as follows:

A critical error has occurred. The type initializer for 'FormatterGenerator' threw an exception.

[image: formattergenerator]

Comment: what version of .net are you using? Do you currently have .net 3.5 installed or just .net 2.0?

Comment: The web server is running .NET 3.5 but the application pool is running 4.0. Haven't had any problems leaving it on 4.0. I believe DotNetNuke is still running on 3.5 as well.

Comment: Yes, dnn 6 can run on .net 3.5. Nothing similar has ever happened to me. If this is a clean install it must be either something that went wrong during the installation or there's something wrong with the configuration. I'm guessing I'm not telling you anything new. Try changing the app pool to integrated if it's on classic, it once solved me a weird issue like this. You should try posting it on the DNN forums or send a ticket. I own a professional license of DNN and I could ask them about this if you want. Please let me know.

Comment: After a couple of different attempts to fix this following threads online, I'm still unable to solve this. If you want to submit a ticket to their support I'd be highly grateful. I'm out of ideas on how to fix this.

Comment: I've actually found something interesting. On my sites I've found that by going to both Admin->Site Settings and the Profile pages, those are causing a 302 redirect which would cause this error to occur. I have other instances that are not exhibiting these behaviors and they are correctly resolving without the 302 redirect response.

Comment: Thinking about it now though it's probably redirecting to Default.aspx to show the exception...